# Replace columns in a 2D numpy array by columns from another2D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I have two 2D arrays, I want to create arrays that are copy of the first one and then replace some columns by others from the second one.

```
M1 = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
               [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])

M2 = np.array([[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
               [4.1, 5.1, 6.1., 4.2, 5.2, 6.2]])
```

I want to do a loop that can give the following arrays:

```
M3 = np.array([[1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0], 
               [4.1, 5.0, 6.0, 4.2, 5.0, 6.0]])

M4 = np.array([[1.0, 2.1, 3.0, 1.0, 2.2, 3.0], 
               [4.0, 5.1, 6.0, 4.0, 5.2, 6.0]])

M5 = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.2], 
               [4.0, 5.0, 6.1, 4.0, 5.0, 6.2]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
selector = [1,0,0,1,0,0]
np.where(selector,M2,M1)
# array([[1.1, 2. , 3. , 1.2, 2. , 3. ],
#        [4.1, 5. , 6. , 4.2, 5. , 6. ]])
selector = [0,1,0,0,1,0]
np.where(selector,M2,M1)
# array([[1. , 2.1, 3. , 1. , 2.2, 3. ],
#        [4. , 5.1, 6. , 4. , 5.2, 6. ]])
```

etc.

Or in a loop:

```
M3,M4,M5 = (np.where(s,M2,M1) for s in np.tile(np.identity(3,bool), (1,2)))
M3
# array([[1.1, 2. , 3. , 1.2, 2. , 3. ],
#        [4.1, 5. , 6. , 4.2, 5. , 6. ]])
M4
# array([[1. , 2.1, 3. , 1. , 2.2, 3. ],
#        [4. , 5.1, 6. , 4. , 5.2, 6. ]])
M5
# array([[1. , 2. , 3.1, 1. , 2. , 3.2],
#        [4. , 5. , 6.1, 4. , 5. , 6.2]])
```

Alternatively, you can copy `M1` and then slice in `M2`. This is more verbose but should be faster:

```
n = 3
Mj = []
for j in range(n):
    Mp = M1.copy()
    Mp[:,j::n] = M2[:,j::n]
    Mj.append(Mp)

M3,M4,M5 = Mj
```

Comment: what if i have a very large number of columns and I want to specify that every 'n' columns  pick one.

Comment: @ElenaPopa is the number of columns a mulitple of `n`?

Comment: @ElenaPopa never mind. I've added a method that works regardless. I'm pretty sure it will also be faster, so if your arrays are big I recommend it over the other.